# Many to Many mapping not working - EF 4.1 RC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

**UPDATE:** After a bit more research it seems *a number* of my many-to-many mappings aren't working. Hmmm...

I'm upgrading a data access project from EF 4.1 CTP4 to EF 4.1 RC and I'm having trouble with the new `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` setup.

Specifically I'm having an issue with a Many-to-Many relationship. I'm getting a `Sequence contains no elements` exception when I'm trying to get the `.First()` item.

The particular exception isn't really that interesting. All it's saying is that there are no items **BUT** I know there should be items in the collection - so there must be an issue with my new mappings.

Here's the code I have so far:

**Product Model**

```
public class Product : DbTable
{
    //Blah

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Categories { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        //Blah
        Categories = new List<Tag>();
    }
}
```

**BaseConfiguration**

```
public class BaseConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : DbTable
{
    public BaseConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(x => x.UpdatedOn);
        this.Property(x => x.CreatedOn);
    }
}
```

**ProductConfiguration**

```
public class ProductConfiguration : BaseConfiguration<Product> 
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Product");

        //Blah

        this.HasMany(x => x.Categories)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("Tag_Id");
                m.MapRightKey("Product_Id");
                m.ToTable("ProductCategory");
            });
    }
}
```

**Previous CTP4 Mapping the worked!**

```
this.HasMany(x => x.Categories)
    .WithMany()
    .Map("ProductCategory", (p, c) => new { Product_Id = p.Id, Tag_Id = c.Id  });
```

Can anyone see anything that needs fixing? Let me know if you want me to provide more code.

**EDIT: More Code**

**DbTable**

```
public class DbTable : IDbTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

**Tag**

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public virtual TagType TagType { get; set; }
}
```

**TagConfiguration**

```
public class TagConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tag>
{
    public TagConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Tags");

        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("tag_id");
        this.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(300).HasColumnName("tag_name");
        this.Property(x => x.Slug).HasMaxLength(500).HasColumnName("tag_slug");
        this.Property(x => x.Visible).HasColumnName("tag_visible");
        this.HasRequired(x => x.TagType).WithMany(tt => tt.Tags).Map(m => m.MapKey("tagtype_id"));
    }
}
```

Yes, this is a legacy database with naming conventions [up to boohai](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=up%20the%20boohai).

I know the `Tag` class must be wired up correctly because Product has another property `Specialization` which is also mapped to `Tag` and it loads correctly. But do note that it's mapped in a one-to-many manner. So it seems to be the many-to-many with `Tag`.

I'll start checking out if any many-to-many associations are working.

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else because I just used your code and it works for me.

Comment: Niggly! Although I'm very appreciative for you trying out my code - that's not what I want to hear! I turned MARS on because I thought that could be an issue... where else could I start looking?

Comment: It's hard to say. You must show other code snippets becasue problem is pobably not in those you shown.

Comment: Please show your full object model including `DbTable` and `Tag` classes so that we can repro the exception. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, there's some more code... let me know if you still need more.

Comment: Turns out a completely different many-to-many relationship isn't loading either. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify *both* navigation properties to do many to many mapping.

Try adding the lambda in the WithMany property pointing back to the products:

```
this.HasMany(x => x.Categories)
            .WithMany(category=>category.Products)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey(t => t.TagId, "Tag_Id");
                m.MapRightKey(t => t.ProductId, "Product_Id");
                m.ToTable("ProductCategory");
            });
```

(crossing fingers...)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Code-First approach yet, but when working with POCOs I had to enable Lazy-Loading, to make Navigation Properties work. This is of course by design, but I don't know if you have to explicitly enable this behavior for Code-First.

Comment: And how do I do that? #lazyweb

Comment: Ok, so I found that it's enabled by default. Explicitly setting it to true didn't help either :-(

Comment: yep, with EF4.1 dbcontext, lazy loading is enabled by default. :)