# How to get EF 4.1 RC code-first to use correct foreign key?

Tags: many-to-many, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I was using CTP5 and switched to RC1. With no changes to the EntityTypeConfiguration, EF is now trying to look something up by the wrong column name.  It is using the singular rather than the plural of the column name and I can't figure out where it is getting that idea.

Example: Many-to-many

```
//User.Roles
//Role.Users

//User EntityTypeConfiguration

this.HasKey(x => x.Id);

this.HasMany(x => x.Roles)
   .WithMany().Map(m => {
      m.MapLeftKey("Users_Id");
      m.MapRightKey("Roles_Id");
      m.ToTable("UserRoleLinks");
   });
```

Then I get the error:

Invalid column name 'User_Id'.

Where is it getting "User_Id"?  The table Id is "Id"; The join table is explicitly stated as "Users_Id"  What changed between CTP5 and RC1 that would have caused this?

**UPDATE:**

I am using the "modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>()" is that one not supported anymore?  Could this be the problem? I'm not sure what the default behavior is now.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfig()); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  The short answer is that I needed to define both sides of the many-to-many relationship because each class participates with a reciprocal collection (User.Roles and Role.Users).  Apparently that wasn't necessary with CTP5.

See: [Many to Many mapping not working - EF 4.1 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423819/many-to-many-mapping-not-working-ef-4-1-rc/5438785#5438785)

To stick with my example, here is the correct syntax.

```
this.HasMany(x => x.Roles)
   .WithMany(r => r.Users).Map(m => {
      m.MapLeftKey("Users_Id");
      m.MapRightKey("Roles_Id");
      m.ToTable("UserRoleLinks");
   });
```

There are a couple pitfalls which obscured the simple solution for me.

1) Only define the relationship once.  I was defining the many-to-many relationship from both perspectives in different EntityTypeConfiguration<T> classes, which is not necessary and brings its own errors.

2) Don't mix up the fields you use for the MapLeftKey and MapRightKey. The order is intuitive but I am guessing it is easily something that could get mixed up through copy/paste and what-not.

Answer (score 0):

The Foreign Key naming convention changed in `EF 4.1 RC`.

The problem is basically that EF now expects the FK to be called `User_ID` (singular), and the RC provides no ability to configure custom conventions.

If EF recreated the database for you, just change your mappings to `User_Id`. If you're stuck with a production database I'd recommend using [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) to rename the Foreign Keys in your database.

This answer (gotten from a question of mine, see below) worked for me painlessly and seamlessly on a production database.

---

### Useful references

- A question of mine about EF 4.1 RC
  naming conventions:
  [EF 4.1 messing things up. Has FK naming strategy changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344474/ef-4-1-messing-things-up-has-fk-naming-strategy-changed).
- For further reference, here's a [list
  of changes in
  RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx).

Comment: But OP doesn't use default names generated by convention.

Comment: @Ladislav - And still it's complainig about a non-existent FK. AFAIK, one of the things that didn't make it to this release is the ability to add custom conventions in Code First. Am I completely off track?

Comment: @Sergi: Yes anything about adding convetions was marked internal but still this should not be affected by convention. Mapping key column to different name should work.

Comment: @Ladislav - Mhm... Ok. All yours then. You're the Fluent API master; I've barely touched it ;)

Comment: @Sergi: Here is some working example. I tested it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544255/entity-with-many-to-many-relationship-creation-fails-after-upgrading-to-rc/5544859#5544859 I just played with it and it works.

Comment: @Ladislav - Cool, thanks for the heads up =) Do you think I should delete my answer then, as it could be misleading?

Comment: @Sergi: I don't know. You can be right. If OP incorrectly setup usage of his configuration the convention can be applied.

Comment: @Ladislav - OK, I'll wait and see. Thanks for the additional info though.

Comment: OK, so the Convention was not the issue.  It was the WithMany().  It needed the reciprocal definition WithMany(r => r.Users). I had tried that before but the relationship was defined in both class configs and didn't work. Once I deleted the Roles config the problem was fixed. Should I answer my own question or update the original?

Comment: @jedatu - if you found a solution, answer your own question and mark your answer as the right one. It will help others along.